# How to Filter a Query On a One to Many Relationship via Linq

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, one-to-many

I have a Product and a Part Table. Here is the association:

```
Create Table Product
{
   Id int,
   Name nvarchar(max)
}

Create Table Part
{
   Id int,
   Name nvarchar (max),
   ProductID int (foreign key to Product.Id),
   SomeCategoryId int
}
```

Now, I want to return a list of Products with a List of Parts that only include a SomeCategoryId of 200.

**Rules:**

- If a Part.SomeCategoryId <> 200, do not include the Part
- If no Part.SomeCategoryId == 200 corresponding to the Product via Part.Product.Id, remove the entire Product.

How would make my code below more efficient?

```
prods = db.Products.OrderBy(o => o.Name).Select(pr => new ProductViewModel
{
    Id = pr.Id,
    Name = pr.Name,
    Parts = pr.Parts.OrderBy(o => o.Name).Select(prt => new PartViewModel
    {
        Id = prt.Id,
        Name = prt.Name,
        SomeCategoryId = prt.SomeCategoryId
    }).Where(w => w.SomeCategoryId == 200).ToList()
}).ToList();

foreach(var prod in prods)
{
    var isSomeCategory = false;
    foreach (var part in prod.Parts)
    {
        if (part.SomeCategoryId == 200)
        {
            isSomeCategory = !isSomeCategory;
        }
    }

    if (isSomeCategory == false)
    {
        prods.Remove(prod);
    }
}
```

Comment: You only need to filter products with parts from the end result. Whether it's more efficient to do this in memory or in the database is something for you to try out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about...

```
prods = db.Products.Where(pr => pr.Parts.Any(p => p.SomeCategoryId == 200)).OrderBy(o => o.Name).Select(pr => new ProductViewModel
{
    Id = pr.Id,
    Name = pr.Name,
    Parts = pr.Parts.OrderBy(o => o.Name).Select(prt => new PartViewModel
    {
        Id = prt.Id,
        Name = prt.Name,
        SomeCategoryId = prt.SomeCategoryId
    }).Where(w => w.SomeCategoryId == 200).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: This is soooooooooooooooooooo slow! Might it be because I have absolutely no data in Parts?

Comment: is it getting faster if you move the where before the select?